# Android SQLite catch error using execSQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a method that runs a INSERT SQL statment that are got from external soruces and not from the android device. The incoming statments can cause duplicate records and I want the android device to ignore the sql statments if they cause duplicates. The method is:

```
    ourDatabase.execSQL(sql)
```

The table its inserting the data into has the following column that prevents duplicates

```
    KEY_CONCATA + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY , " +
```

Should this be unique and not primary key?

The system at the moment recognizes its causing a duplicate and ends the program, I want it to catch the error and stop it being inserted into the database if its a duplicate.

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a `TEXT PRIMARY KEY` and a primary key is unique by default...  What is the error?

Comment: column concata is not unique (code 19)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `KEY_CONCATA TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE` and when insert use `insertWithOnConflict` with `SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE` flag

Comment: Im not sure if this will work, because the incoming is a SQL statment e.g INSERT INTO database_table WHERE..... im guessing such a input would not work with insertWithOnConflict?

Comment: Try KEY_CONCATA TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE

Comment: Or `KEY_CONCATA + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT IGNORE, " +`

Comment: @Sam I think your statement requires NOT NULL because sqlite allows PRIMARY_KEY field to be null

Comment: KEY_CONCATA + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE , " + is what worked fo rme